# set-cookie is sent as a header but can't see cookie in application > cookies (in chrome)

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, axios, http-headers

This all works locally but not in prod. I am using express and node to set my jwt token on login (POST /login). I can see the cookie in the network tab via the Set-Cookie header. It is being set with httpOnly:true, secure: true, and sameSite: "none". However, I can't see it in the Application > Cookies tab in Chrome for my site. Any ideas on how to fix this?

axios frontend call:

```
      const config = {
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: "same-origin",
      };

         axios
          .post(
            `${endpoint}/login`,
            {
              email: loginData.email,
              password: loginData.password,
            },
            config
          )
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.status);
          });
```

express:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: [
    "https://example.io", // prod url
    "https://www.example.io", // prod url with www
    "http://localhost:3000",
  ],
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.example.io");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Set-Cookie");
  next();
});
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {email, password} = req.body;
    const response = await pool.query(
      "SELECT id, (password = crypt($1, password)) AS verified FROM users WHERE email = $2",
      [password, email]
    );
    if (response.error) {
      console.log(response.error);
    }

    let {verified, id} = response.rows[0];
    if (verified) {
      const options = {
        expiresIn: "1h",
      };
      const token = jwt.sign(
        {user_id: id},
        process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        options
      );
      res.cookie("token", token, {
        maxAge: 86400000,
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "none",
      });
      res.json(response.rows[0]);
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json({message: "Invalid credentials"});
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```